# Need help fix css bug in chrome / safari

Tags: css, webkit

Just helping my friend here. He got this website in development:

http://themagicbeads.com/en/15-dresses

When open with firefox, there is no error. However when open with chrome or safari, got striketrough bug in the product description as in the picture below:

[image]

How to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `li` elements are descendants of `strike` elements, which is giving them the *strike-through* effect.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you wrote something like this:

```
<strike>Add to cart<strike>
```

You need to close the `strike` tag, not open a new one. Change that to this:

```
<strike>Add to cart</strike>
```